# Need to "Prove by Contradiction" that in any graph with at least two vertices, there are at least two vertices of the same degree.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Need to "Prove by Contradiction" that in any graph with at least two vertices, there are at least two vertices of the same degree.

To prove by contradiction referring to the pigeonhole principle, I have the following so far for my proof:

**Hypothesis**: If a graph has atleast two vertices then the graph does *not* have atleast two nodes of the same degree.

**Conclusion** This is proven false by logical contradiction since a simple graph needs to have atleast two vertices referred to as the pigeonhole principle.

Any feedback and corrections for my proof is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find this proof complete or convincing. To what sets are you applying the pigeonhole principle? You need to be specific instead of just naming the tool without its context. Furthermore, your proof never uses the contradiction hypothesis and thus isn't really a proof by contradiction (even if the argument were complete).

Comment: 1: incomplete and confusing question! 2: the proof is incomplete! Please fix the first of the two so you could get reasonable answers.

Comment: Please include the problem in the body of the post. The subject line is not part of the podt, just like the envelope is not part of the letter inside.

Comment: Moreover, a simple graph can have one or even zero vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Make the pigeonhole principle more explicit in your setting. The pigeons are the $n$ vertices, and the "holes" are the possible degrees, ranging from $0$ to $n-1$.  Note that degree $0$ and degree $n-1$ cannot be both attained in the same $n$-vertex graph.